# jQuery Problem receiving html variable from PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm generating a bunch of tinymce edit boxes by sending it's content to javascript through php.

I'm doing something like

```
<script>
addBox('<?$content?>');
</script>
```

The problem is that everytime the text sent has a "/" character the function is broke an returns an error like:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I found it to return this error at least with this char... Don't know if it'll happen with others. The function is giving error when called like:

```
addBox("&lt;p&gt;Fundada em 2000 e inserida no &lt;strong&gt;Grupo CIL&lt;/strong&gt;, a CilNet &amp;eacute; uma empresa de Servi&amp;ccedil;os de Engenharia na &amp;aacute;rea das Tecnologias de Informa&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o, com compet&amp;ecirc;ncias em Redes de Comunica&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o de Dados, Voz e V&amp;iacute;deo.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Tendo como base uma larga experi&amp;ecirc;ncia no mercado nacional, a CilNet assume-se como um parceiro tecnol&amp;oacute;gico no sector empresarial, com especializa&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o em solu&amp;ccedil;&amp;otilde;es tecnol&amp;oacute;gicas pioneiras a n&amp;iacute;vel mundial.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;");
```

Can anyone help?

The code for addBox is as follows:

```
function addBox(text){
    elem = "txt" + window.counter;

    var tiny = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/ajax.php?act=inserebox",
        data: "value=txt" + window.counter + "&text="+encodeURIComponent(text),
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    $('.more_boxes').append(tiny);
    //$(tiny).append('.more_boxes');


    tinyMCE.init({
       url:'../js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/ibrowser',
       mode:"exact",
       elements: elem,
       theme:"advanced",
       height:"220",
       entity_encoding : "raw",
       plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,table,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,inlinepopups,ibrowser",
       theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
       theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
       theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
       theme_advanced_resizing : false
    });
    window.counter+=1;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is addBox doing?  Definitely smells like an encoding issue.

Comment: problem is in the addBox call not in the function itself...

Comment: Did you try decoding your Html - http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/htmlencode/decode.aspx

Comment: Please provide some addBox pseudo code.

Comment: Kris, decode will only return more conflict chars like ' or " no?? I tried encoding and no luck. the function addBox is on top although it returns the error always before

Comment: decode doesn't work aas expected

Comment: this one because the value coming from database: addBox('<?$content?>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's built-in [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to escape illegal characters before they get passed to the tinymce box. You will need to do this to the $content var before passing it to the JS script.

EDIT:

Try a combination of decoded HTML and addSlashes like this:

```
<?php
    // Code to create $content var here //
    $content = addSlashes($content);
?>

<script>
    <![CDATA[
        addBox('<?php echo $content; ?>');
    ]]>
</script>
```

If you don't enclose your Javascript with `<![CDATA[]]>`, then you'll get errors if angle'd brackets are found, because it'll be interpreted as the start of an HTML tag.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the repply! unfortunatly the problems persists... changed it to        $content=addslashes($row->content);
       $this->out.='<script>
        addBox("'.$content.'");
       </script>';

Comment: Hey dSquared!! Thanks for the tip. At first I was getting an "unexpected token: <" then I putted all in the same line like: //<![CDATA[addBox("'.$content.'");//]]> and I got rid of that error. But it still doesn't work... Now it seems to break in new lines :/

Comment: Hi!! Had to adapt your answer for the newlines and some older browser compatibility. I'm editing your answer to place the final code and accepting it! Thanks once again ;)